# Files not present in Windows 8

Tags: 12.04

I had downloaded a file while using Ubuntu. But can't find the same file while in my machine while using Windows 8.

Comment: That is expected, as Windows can't access linux file systems.

Comment: Check [this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/).

Comment: This is a comment not a question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on the scenario:

### Running Ubuntu from a Live-DVD

If you downloaded the file in a Live-Ubuntu and saved it somewhere in your Ubuntu user directory it is gone as this was only saved in memory.

### Running Ubuntu in a dual-boot environment

The file will still be there on the partition(s) used by Ubuntu, but inaccessible by Windows as Linux normally uses a different file System Windows can't read by default. Just reboot into Ubuntu, find the file and copy it to the windows partition.